# Can Asp:Label Value be manipulated by user when the label is set as hidden?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an application where i use ASP labels/inputs and set their visibility to hidden to store critical values.

```
<asp:Label ID="userid" runat="server" Text="" Visible="false">   
        </asp:Label>
```

As expected these labels dont show up directly on the webpage but instead div like the one below is placed in the webpage:

```
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="n6XWzGQDXHjDGVPZuZa....">
</div>
```

I wanted to ask if the user can change these values and manipulate or find the actual value for such labels and inputs!

Thanks!

Comment: If the values exist client-side, even base-64 encoded, and the server then relies on and uses those values then *yes* the client can manipulate those values.  *Never* implicitly trust anything that comes from the client.  *Never* send critical information to the client that they shouldn't have.  Now is a good time to re-think *why* these values are being stored in a UI label in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, no they can't change the label text. (assuming visible = false).

Remember, if you set a control. Visible = false, then in fact the .net system does NOT send that control down to the client side.

In other words, say we do this:

simple markup:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="My label text" 
            ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
    </div>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Hide the label"
        OnClientClick="MyHideToggle();return false;"
        />

    <script>
        function MyHideToggle() {
            // hide the label, or show it if hidden
            var MyLabel = $('#Label1')
            if (MyLabel.is(":visible"))
               MyLabel.hide()
            else
               MyLabel.show()
        }
    </script>
</form>
```

and now say we have this server side code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //Label1.Visible = false;
            //Label1.Text = "super zoo";
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Print(Label1.Text);
    }
```

Ok, so on page load, we set the label text. With above code, our JavaScript toggle code works fine. and the value we set the label to (on first page load) WILL persist.

but, what happens now if we do this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Label1.Visible = false;
            Label1.Text = "super zoo";
        }
    }
```

Ok, so this means:

We did set a value of the Lable - IT WILL persit in view state.

But, our js code can't work now. When you set Lable1.Visbile = false, then it DOES NOT get renderd on the client side.

So, the js code can't work.

But, you WILL see the button click to display the label text (what we changed) text DOES work.

How can this be?

Well, in this case? That encrypted blob and mess you see for view state?

Well, view state is STILL maintained for controls - EVEN ones that don't get rendered and sent to the client side.

So, can they change the text of a label that is visible = false, and not rendered?

Well, for all practical purposes? No, Unless we assume that the encrypted view state has be cracked.

so possible? Perhaps.

So , for the most part practical? No, not really practical.

So, a text box, or label? They do have automatic state management, and it goes into that encrypted view state blob. And that IS SENT to the client side.

But, do keep in mind the ramifications of controls not being sent.

For example, if I want to hide the label, but STILL want the JavaScript (client side code) to work?

Then I can't use visible = false, but have to hide the control with style, and use display:normal, or display:none, say like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Label1.Style.Add("display", "none");
            Label1.Text = "super zoo";
        }
    }
```

Now, the control WILL be hidden, will be sent to the client side. At this point, yes, someone can rather quite easy mess or change the label text.

I think as a general approach? If you hide a control, (visible = false), then you are secure enough for most use cases. And if you do hide a control, then you will NOT see the control in the markup, nor will it be sent to client side. And thus as noted, any JavaScript client code cannot work, nor operate on that control.

But, the label "text" we modified does in fact exist in the client side browser - and it exists in the encrypted View State blob that you noted in your post.

but, if you term "hidden" means only a style display:none, and NOT some server (code behind) setting of Visible = False? Then yes, that control and label and text can most certainly be modified by client side code - be it JavaScript, or a user flipping their browsers into debug mode.

So the "way" you hide that control will change what the user can and cannot do. Using style display:none (which is what jQuery does for hide() and show(), then the control still exists in plane view in the pages markup.  And even in this case - you can't see it, but flipping into the page source in the browser - the control will be in plain view - and yes, it can be changed by the user - will relative ease and skill.